# Firebase Google Auth "Authentication Disabled"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am checking out Google Auth with the new firebase (web) and I am getting this "Authentication Disabled" message when I try to pop up Google Auth on click of a button.

I have clearly enabled Google sign in  from Auth and followed configuration example from https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html.

I have generated client ID and secret as per the document.

Here are my urls configured in Google console
https://auth.firebase.com
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/exampleXXX-XXX-loss/auth/google/callback

I have pasted the client ID and secret in Web SDK configuration for Google Signin

What am I missing ?

Comment: The documentation link you provided is the V2 firebase documentation. Please check the new sdk documentation if you plan on using the new SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/#key_functions

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to go with your current project is upgrade it to the newest Firebase version. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/ scroll down to the section "Your projects currently at Firebase.com" and hit the "Import" button.
After this you'll be able to use the new capabilities of Firebase 3 and specifically for Google Sign-in you can check this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Have fun out there!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the newest firebase sdk. Or try to switch to google firebase. Google firebase is similar to firebase, however, it is easier to implement the code, in your existing project.